# Django template for loop

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a template where I get certain variables back.
One variable is instance.category which outputs: "words words words" which are values split by spaced.

When I use the code below I get letter by letter back and not the words.

```
{% for icon in instance.category  %}
  <p>{{ icon }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Output

```
<p>w</p>
<p>o</p>
<p>r</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>w</p>
....
```

I need:

```
<p>word</p>
<p>word</p>
<p>word</p>
```

The Django plugin code

```
from cmsplugin_filer_image.cms_plugins import FilerImagePlugin
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from models import Item

class PortfolioItemPlugin(FilerImagePlugin):
    model = Item
    name = "Portfolio item"
    render_template = "portfolio/item.html"
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', 'category',)
        }),
        (None, {
            'fields': (('image', 'image_url',), 'alt_text',)
        }),
        (_('Image resizing options'), {
            'fields': (
                'use_original_image',
                ('width', 'height', 'crop', 'upscale'),
                'use_autoscale',
            )
        }),
        (_('More'), {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': (('free_link', 'page_link', 'file_link', 'original_link', 'target_blank'),)
        }),
    )

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PortfolioItemPlugin)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you show us the view to have a look at category ?

Comment: We overridden the FilerImage plugin to add an extra field for a portfolio item. Does this help you (updated)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your separator is always `" "` and `category` is a string, you don't actually need a custom template filter. You could simply call `split` with no parameters:

```
{% for icon in instance.category.split %}
  <p>{{ icon }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are passing a string `instance.category` into the template and then iterating over its chars.

Instead, pass a list to the template: `instance.category.split()` which will split your `words words words` string into the list `['words', 'words', 'words']`:

```
>>> s = "words words words"
>>> s.split()
['words', 'words', 'words']
```

---

Or, you can define a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that will split a string into the list:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def split(s, splitter=" "):
    return s.split(splitter)
```

Then, use it in the template this way:

```
{% for icon in instance.category|split %}
    <p>{{ icon }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am using the custom filter but I get this error: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for icon in instance.category|split:" " any ideas?

Comment: I fixed it with the comment above from @Augusto Men, Thanks anyway, upvoted.

Comment: I've removed the useless `{% with  %}` to be more concise.

Comment: @MaximeLorant yeah, it was originally without the `with`, then I've tried to fix the OP's problem that way.

Comment: @NielsenRamon as Augusto Men correctly pointed out: you don't need a custom filter in case you are always splitting by space. Btw, I've updated the answer - should work in your case too.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but it might help someone (it was the problem I had).
If you have a point in the form: (x, y). then you need:

```
{% for x, y in points %}
    There is a point at {{ x }},{{ y }}
{% endfor %}
```

And for key-value pairs:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

source: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/) (check the for section)